# Is it mathematically valid to take the limit of an **equation** as opposed to an expression?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram Alpha seems to think it's okay to write this: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n=\frac{n^2}{n})=True$$ I understand what is meant, and also why it returns True, but is this a mathematically valid statement? If not, is there a more correct way to write the same thing? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think what it's doing is replacing $n=n^2/n$ with true, since it can assume that $n\neq 0$. Then it's taking the limit of "true," whatever that means.

Comment: @MattSamuel Good point, but is it not true that as all instances of $n$ on both sides of the equation approach ∞, the truth of the equation 'approaches' True?

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Whatever it is, it's weird.

Comment: $lim_{n \to \infty} (n>100)=True$? I would ignore this, and just say $n>100$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @AndresMejia But is it really accurate to say $n>100$ as $n\rightarrow ∞$? Isn't that only true for $n>100$?

Comment: yeah, well certainly as $ n \to \infty$... $n>100$ eventually becomes true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be interpreting this as taking the limit of both sides of the equation, because then you get $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^2}{n}$, which is a true statement. However, I think in common usage, people would interpret something like this as an abuse of notation, which, despite the name, isn't necessarily a bad thing, but you do have to be careful to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I would hope that's not what it's doing, because then you could replace $n$ with $e^n$ and get the same answer.

Comment: Damn, you're right. That's my bad; ignore me.

Comment: @MattSamuel What? Replacing $n$ with $e^n$ in $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n=\frac{n^2}{n})=True$$ does yield True.

Comment: @MicahWindsor I think you misinterpreted what I meant. I tested and my interpretation was correct. $\lim_{n\to\infty}(e^n=n)$ gives you false.

Comment: @MattSamuel OH. Sorry about that, you said "replace $n$ with $e^n$", so that's what I assumed you meant. In that case, I guess you were probably right after all lol.